# Force drop asp.net membership

Tags: asp.net-membership

I'm trying to remove all the views, tables etc the aspnet_regsql.exe command created.
Running the wizard again but for uninstalling tells me there are records in there so I cannot delete it.

Removing all the users is a pain as I would need to unravel the whole structure, remove all the keys etc.

Is there an easy way to get rid of the whole thing?

Answer (score 0):

You can write t-sql script to drop those objects.
or you just create a new database and migrate the data only you need?

Comment: Hmm, the last option is a no-go. The first option is what I was fearing. Is there no out-of-the-box option?

Comment: I want to avoid to do it manually because I want to make sure not to miss anything

Comment: you do not miss anything... you can find the uninstall script of the aspnet_regsql uses. and modify the script as needed.